# Detect user change on knockout observable text field

Tags: knockout.js

I have an html input text field which is bound to a property via knockout ko.observable(). This property gets regularly updated via an ajax call. The same property is also editable by the user. If the user changes the property I have to write it back to the server. To get a notification if the property changed I added an subscription. How can I differ whether the property was changed by the ajax call or by the user via UI? Right now I get notified for both updates.

Thanks!

Comment: Set a flag when doing the AJAX call and check this flag in the subscribe function...

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This works but I thought there must be something smarter.